# Running a check_output in python3 with mediainfo produces an error, even though the same call in terminal works fine

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, mediainfo

This is the code:

```
try:
    s = check_output(['mediainfo', '--Inform=General;%Format%', filename])  # Gets the output from mediainfo
```

When running it, I get

```
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['mediainfo', '--Inform=General;%Format%', 'xyz']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

When running `mediainfo --Inform='Video;%Format%' s03e07.mkv` in a terminal, I get the desired output though, so what's going on here?

Comment: Where is filename coming from? Add the end of the tracrback where you have the filename string

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with the first two arguments. there are two strong possibilities, you are reading from a file and you have trailing whitespace on the filename:

```
"sample.mkv\n"
```

Or you *current working directory* is not where the file is so you need to pass the full path or set `cwd="path_to_filr_dir"` in *check_output* call.

Comment: So how would I have to modify this part? s = check_output(['mediainfo', '--Inform=General;%Format%', filename]) I already tried replacing filename with "filename\n" but that didn't help.

Comment: Wherever the file is set you cwd, `check_output(['mediainfo', '--Inform=General;%Format%', filename], cwd="path_to_file_dir") `